# How to isolate an element of a reactive list in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Let's say I have the following test app below. What I am looking for is how to replicate the functionality of the `reactiveValues` solution. If you play around with the app you will notice one difference in the way `isolate` impacts functionality. With reactive values, I can choose elements in the reactive list to isolate.

So if the user clicks button 1, the time will always change. So the time will always print in the observe. If the user clicks the same button, since the `data` is not changing, only the time will display. If you switch clicks between buttons, both the name of the button and the time will display.

It doesn't seem like you can replicate this functionality using `reactive`. My issue is with the real scenario I am using `reactivePoll`. My reactivePoll returns a list `myData` let's say. What I want to do is be able to `isolate` only when `myData$firstel` changes. But it seems that any reactive paradigm that updates from `myData` will update whether `myData$firstel` changes or `myData$secondel` changes. Is there a way to solve this? I have tried converting my reactivePoll to a reactiveValues but it doesn't seem to work

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button1","Button 1"),
  actionButton("button2","Button 2"),
  textOutput("output1"),
  textOutput("output2")
)

server <- function(input,output,session){

  myreactval <- reactiveValues(data = NULL, selection = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$button1,{
    myreactval$data <- Sys.time()
    myreactval$selection <- "button1"
  })
  observeEvent(input$button2,{
    myreactval$data <- Sys.time()
    myreactval$selection <- "button2"
  })


  myreact <- eventReactive(input$button1,{
    res <- list()
    res$data <- Sys.time()
    res$selection <- "button1"
    return(res)
  })


  output$output1 <- renderText({ myreact()$data })
  output$output2 <- renderText({ myreact()$selection })

  # REACTIVE SOLUTION
  # observe({
  #   print(myreact()$selection)
  # })
  # observe({
  #   print(isolate(myreact())$data)
  # })

  # REACTIVE VALUES SOLUTION
  observe({
    print(myreactval$selection)
  })
  observe({
    print(isolate(myreactval)$data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet to convert a reactive list `reacList` to a reactiveValues object `reacVals`.

```
  reacVals <- reactiveValues()
  observe(
      purrr::imap(reacList(), function(val, name) {
        reacVals[[name]] <- val
      })
    )
```

When any element in `reacList` changes, all elements of the `reactiveValues` are updated. However, these updates update only invalidate further dependencies when an element value has actually changed. This means that you can use `reacVals` to create element-specific dependencies, which is what you wanted to achieve.

I know you already tried converting your `reactivePoll` object to a `reactiveValues` object but this may be a different approach than yours.